# How to merge and sum 2 arrays using excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Given a .csv data file as follows

```
  12,green orange
  1,good egg
  ...
  5,green orange
```

I want to sum-up the first column elements if the second column element is the same. Given the example above, now we should have

```
  17,green orange
   1,good egg
   ...
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Pivot table would work great for this.

Comment: yes, the second column is not <tab> or <space> delimited.

Comment: Also assuming you can import the CSV to Excel without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good option would be to use a Pivot Table (this is practically what they are designed for).

In your case, look into the `SUMIF` formula - [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx) as it doesn't seem you will need such advanced functionlaity.

Copy the list of "keys" (the items) into a separate worksheet and remove duplicates, then just setup `SUMIF` like:

```
key   |   total sum
green |   = SUMIF(dataSheet!B:B, A2, dataSheet!A:A)
```

where you have this in a sheet, and `dataSheet` represents the CSV values you just imported.

Comment: That's very nice. I worked over the same datasheet, and the data is begin in the first row, so I use
       =SUMIF(B:B, B1,A:A ), and then sort and remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to work with variables.

```
Count   |Color
12  |Green
1   |Blue
5   |Green 
7   |Green
3   |Blue
```

Sort the file by the value "Color"

```
Count   |Color
1   |Blue
3   |Blue
12  |Green
7   |Green
5   |Green
```

Put Formula in cell C2 and paste down

```
=IF(B2=B1,(C1+A2),A2)
```

Harvest the sums at the end of each color (i.e. Blue = 4, Green = 24)

[image: Blue]